# gsub regex into a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Given a string like `"this is the {{any}} string"`, I'd like to `gsub` (or similar) `{{any}}` with `/.*/` and then use that entire string as my matcher.

I've tried, as you could guess, `"this is the {{any}} string".gsub("{{any}}", /.*/)`, which gives the error:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into String

Comment: Do you mean you want to literally replace every instance of "{{any}}" with "/.*/" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string = "this is the {{any}} string"
regexp = Regexp.new(Regexp.quote(string).gsub("\\{\\{any\\}\\}", '.*'))
```

How does this work?

- `Regexp.quote` escapes the string such that it matches verbatim
- `gsub` replaces `{{any}}`, which is by now escaped, with `.*`
- `Regexp.new` creates a regexp

Comment: Why not just `Regexp.new(string.gsub('{{any}}', '.*'))`? Your regex escapes spaces (this does not), but other than that the regex is the same.

Comment: I assume that `string` may contain `()` and `.` that they want to match verbatim.

Comment: I see, but `'.*'` is not to be matched verbatem, correct?